# Display text over an image like Newser.com does it (e.g. with a dark background)

Tags: html

I'd like to display text over an image like Newser.com does.
Here is a sample:
[image: http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/8506/newser.jpg]

At first glance this seems simple. But it's proven very challenging for me.

The solution likely lies in some combination of DIV and SPAN (possibly span's nested in block DIV's...?)

Ideas?

(Note 1: Notice how each span of text has a background of a unique length -- e.g. directly under the text)

(Note 2: Don't worry about the opacity value for now. I just basically want to make 4 black text blocks (as shown in the jpg.))

Answer (score 1):

Newser.com seems to produce the images with the text already on them but you can do this using just html and css.

Here is an example of how:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jDdAb